# Что означает [object HTMLParagraphElement]?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть выбор типа доставки в `<input type="radio">` с обработкой JS; выводится выбранный тип вот таким образом: `<output id="product-price"></output>`, но почему то, когда ещё не сделал выбор, щёлкнув на какую-нибудь пустую строчку формы заказа, на месте этого вывода  появляется это сообщение `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`.

Что это такое и как с этим бороться?

Вот фрагменты кода JS:

```
window.onload = function(){ totalPrice = "<?=$_SESSION['total_price']?>"; }

window.onclick = function onclickRadio() {
  var nameRadio = document.getElementsByName('nameRadio');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameRadio.length; i++) {
    if (nameRadio[i].type === 'radio' && nameRadio[i].checked) {
        rezultatRadio = nameRadio[i].value;       

    }
  }
  document.getElementById('rezultatRadio').innerHTML =  rezultatRadio;
  document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML =  new Number (+rezultatRadio) + new Number (+totalPrice);
}

<input type="radio" name="nameRadio" value="300" > Наш курьер (Стоимость доставки 300 руб)
    <input type="radio" name="nameRadio" value="0">Самовывоз
```

Вот html вывод, где появляется это предупреждение:

```
<td align="center"><p id="rezultatRadio"></p> руб </td>
```

Если выводить через , то появляется такое предупреждение: [object HTMLOutputElement]

Пробую теперь вот такой код, вообще ничего не выполняется....:

```
function(){ totalPrice = "<?=$_SESSION['total_price']?>"; }

function showResult() {
  var nameRadio = document.getElementsByName('nameRadio');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameRadio.length; i++) {
    if (nameRadio[i].type === 'radio' && nameRadio[i].checked) {
        rezultatRadio = nameRadio[i].getAttribute('data');       

    }
  }
  document.getElementById('rezultatRadio').innerHTML =  rezultatRadio;
  document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML =  new Number (+rezultatRadio) + new Number (+totalPrice);

}

showResult();
window.onclick = showResult;

<input type="radio" name="nameRadio" data='300' value="300" checked="checked"> Наш курьер (Стоимость доставки 300 руб)
    <input type="radio" name="nameRadio" data='0' value="0">Самовывоз
```

Comment: это значит, что вы вместо строки где-то используете объект типа `<p>`.   без кода больше сказать нельзя.

Comment: Вставил фрагменты кода в тело вопроса.

Comment: Последний код работает, если убрать строку с выводом total-price. Скорее всего проблема тут
еще, если хотите получить число из строки `new Number()` , не лучший вариант, есть унарный плюс, есть `parseInt` и так далее, используйте лучше их

Comment: ThisMan, про parseInt читал, но чего то недопонял и newNumber показалось доступнее....  Буду пробовать.

Comment: ThisMan,попробовал сделать так: document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML =  parseInt (rezultatRadio) + parseInt (totalPrice);     В обычном коде преобразует строку в число, но всё равно с новым кодам ничего не работает.......

Answer (score 1):

1) Обработка клика навешена неправильно.
2) Выводится дефолтный `toString()` объекта ноды параграфа: `<p></p>` (надо значение вставлять, можно получить с помощью `innerHTML`).

Больше сказать без кода нельзя.

Comment: Вставил код в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

У вас элемент ***p*** имеет id='rezultatRadio', по умолчанию браузеры **автоматически создают переменные с id**. То есть у вас изначально есть переменная *rezultatRadio*, которая хранит в себе элемент, с id='rezultatRadio'.

Поэтому первый раз при клике, у вас отображается переменная *rezultatRadio* ( в данном случае это как раз [object HTMLParagraphElement])
Варианты решения:

1. Поменять id у элемента
2. Сменить название переменной rezultatRadio
3. Сменить обработчик ( точнее, повесить его на input-ы, а не на весь window)
4. Сделать один из radio отмеченным по умолчанию ( самый простой способ )

Для теста, создайте элемент с id, и попробуйте сразу при загрузке вывести переменную, с таким же именем, как и id

---

Что бы при загрузке уже было какое-то значение? Тогда так: [демо2](http://jsbin.com/secidijumi/1)
Создали функцию, которую сразу вызываем + вешаем ее на клик по чекбоксу

```
function showResult () {
  var nameRadio = document.getElementsByName('radio1');
    for (var i = 0; i < nameRadio.length; i++) {
      if (nameRadio[i].type === 'radio' && nameRadio[i].checked) {
        rezultatRadio = nameRadio[i].getAttribute('data');         
      }
  }
  document.getElementById('rezultatRadio').innerHTML =  rezultatRadio;
}
showResult();
window.onclick = showResult;
```

Comment: 1-2: если я меняю id или название переменной, то как будет выводится именно выбранное значение? На что поменять id? И на что поменять название переменной?                       3. Нужно как то поменять windows.onclick на input.onclick (таких примеров я ещё не встречал)                                                                                                     4. Если делаю один radio по умолчанию, то в выводе значение не выводится, пока не нажму на какое-нибудь поле в форме...

Comment: @arhat78 [Вот демо](http://jsbin.com/xujizujefo/1/edit?output), если уберете у radio checked, то будет выводится **[object HTMLDivElement]**, если поставите то будет все окей

Comment: ThisMan, ну я пробовал checked, но у меня, как и на демо, при первой загрузке странице не выводит значения (у меня по умолчанию 300 руб, в демо - radio 1), выводит только после нажатия чего-нибудь. А можно, чтобы при первой загрузке значение сразу выводилось?

Comment: ThisMan, в demo2 всё отлично, как мне бы и хотелось, а вот пытаюсь из двух кодов (моего и вашего demo2) собрать один - ничего не получается......  И в input есть data="radio1..2..3" - это что?

Comment: Добавил в мой первый вопрос изменённый код, с которым также ничего не получается; вообще ничего не работает....